# Is there a way through which i can access a request parameter outside the request in nodejs, expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, d3.js, neo4j

I am currently developing a utility using nodejs, expressjs, neo4j, d3.js for visualization but I m stuck up in a particular use case. i.e. search feature what I am doing is taking the search parameter from the user through a form using post request. and then passing the parameter to another get request where I am executing the query in neo4j using that parameter and that get request is used for taking data for visualization in d3.js. But the problem that I am not able to pass the parameter from one (post) request to another (get)request. please let me know how can I achieve this or is there any other better approach that I can use

form code:

```
<form method="post" action="/api/xyz">
                            <h4> Name</h4>
                            <div class="item">
                                <input id="name" type="text" name="searchname" required/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-block">
                                <button type="submit" href="/">Search</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

post request:

```
router.post('/xyz',(req,res,next)=>{
    proteinname = req.body.proteinname
    console.log(proteinname)
    res.render('searchresult')
})
```

get request:

```
router.get('/xyz',(req,res,next)=>{
 name = proteinname 
     session
         .run('Match(a:Protein {name:{nameParam}})-[r]->(b:Protein) Return a, b,r LIMIT 10',{nameParam:name})
         .then(function(neoresult){
res.send(neoresult)
})
```

Comment: You could use server-side sessions, but that can add a lot of complexity. There isn't enough context in your question to understand what other options might be. Could the GET include the protein name as a query parameter, for example.

Comment: can you please tell more about how to use server- side sessions. yes the neo4j query should have proteinname obtained from post request in the get request i.e. what user entered as the searched value

Comment: Search for "Express sessions", there are loads of tutorials etc. I'm saying that the get request doesn't necessarily *have* to share state with the post (indeed requests ought to be stateless), but you haven't given enough information to be more specific than that.

Comment: thank you i will look into the express sessions. I didn't get your point, In the get request I want to search for a particular protein and its related protein for that I have to send the proteinname searched by the user in the neo4j query as nameParam (in the query) based on this get request i am sending data to D3.js and visualizing the data. please let me know what am i missing